# Guess quote_id based on a merged Quote

Tags: magento-1, quote, sales

Here is what I do (simple):

```
$quoteB = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load(1234);
$currentQuote = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
$currentQuote->merge($quoteB);  
$currentQuote->assignCustomer(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer());
$currentQuote->collectTotals()->save();
```

I basically merge a given quote (`1234`) into the current Quote so as the cart is updated with the information I want.

What I can't manage to do, is find some way to retrieve `$quoteB`'s ID from the `$currentQuote`

I could obviously add a field to `sales_flat_quote` and store the quotes which are merged into said field, but I'm looking for a native way for Magento to do it, if such method exists.

Answer (score 0):

Merging does not preserve the id of the merged quote, so you will have to introduce a new field, as you suggested.

Comment: I have Offers (custom dev), which are bound to a Quote. What I end up doing, is saving the list of merged Offers (i.e. quotes) into the current Quote in a custom field. This way, once I'm in the order, I can retrieve the list of Quotes from the list of Orders contained in the related Quote.